# Can I include domain name in php error log?

Tags: php, logging

I host multiple sites on multiples domain names from one Directory with symbolic links. It is working well but some errors and warnings are difficult to analyse from php error log because it indicates only the directory and file where the errors are. Adding the domain name would be very helpful.

Comment: Well you could set up your own custom error logger and log whatever you want,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All requests to php scripts on a http server are usually logged to the http servers log files. The options you have to control what is written to that log file is contained in the documentation of the http server you are using.

When referring to the domain name the request was sent to (as opposed to the domain name the request was sent *from*), then the typical approach is to have separate log files for separate domains. You can configure that in your http servers configuration.

I am not aware of an option to directly include the requested domain name inside the php logging routines. That is, because PHP does not really know about that under typical setups. You could try writing your own logging handler and include information from the $_REQUEST super global. But I'd say it is much easier to check the http servers log files.

Comment: Today I have to match apache acces log with php log (with time). But it's realy impractical. You suggest that I could log php error in apache log file ?

Comment: As said: you do have to option to register your own log handler: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Thanks arkascha, but I would rather to rely on PHP or Apache Option to do so.

Comment: Why that? It would be a 5 line routine... Anyway, as said I am not aware of such option.

Comment: I will watch to create a custom log handler. Thanks arkascha.